# Amazon AWS and GetCallerIdentity

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-sts

I'm working on an AWS project. We want to be able to issue STS temporary security credentials, with limited permissions, in order to access AWS services. We're working in .Net Core with C#.

We're using STS `AssumeRoleAsync()`, which is the .Net SDK's method for using the AWS [AssumeRole](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) action, to generate these credentials. The response from the call to `AssumeRoleAsync()` is an `AssumeRoleResponse` object, which is comprised in part of an `AssumeRoleUser` object and a `Credentials` object. One of the properties of `AssumedRoleUser` is `AssumedRoleId`, which is in the form of `role-id:role-session-name`.

We have a **Lambda function** which handles calling `AssumeRoleAsync` and returning the generated credentials in the form of a JSON object. That Lambda function is called via an **API Gateway** method.

All of this is working fine. The above was just to set the scene.

The next thing we want to be able to do is to use the STS temporary credentials to make other calls into AWS services. When that happens, we want be able to use `GetCallerIdentity()` to retrieve the `AssumedRoleId` for the person to whom the credentials were issued. In particular, the `role-session-name` is of interest to us.

So to try to accomplish this, I created another Lambda function behind another API Gateway method. I set this API Gateway method to use `AWS_IAM` authorization in its **Method Request** configuration. In its **Integration Request**, I configured it to `Invoke with caller credentials`. The Lambda function simply accepts the incoming request and calls `GetCallerIdentity()` and returns the result. I used the credentials returned from the previous `AssumeRoleAsync()` call in the request's authorization header.

Based on the information found in the docs for [GetCallerIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) and in the [Principal Table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#principaltable) to which that page refers, I expect to receive the following items in response from the `GetCallerIdentity()` call:

- `Account`
- `Arn`
- `UserId` (this is the important bit for this discussion)

The `UserId` should be in the form of `role-id:caller-specified-role-name`, exactly the same form in which the `AssumedRoleId` from the call to `AssumeRoleAsync` was returned. That would allow me to get the `caller-specified-role-name` and do what we need to do with it.

But that isn't what is returned in the `UserId` property of the response from `GetCallerIdentity()`.

Instead, all that the `UserId` property contains is the `role-id` — it completely omits the essential `caller-specified-role-name`.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Am I overlooking something simple? Could this be a bug in the response from `GetCallerIdentity`?

I'm using the following Amazon SDK components and versions to make these various calls:

- Amazon.Lambda.Core/1.0.0
- Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json/1.1.0
- AWSSDK.Core/3.3.14
- AWSSDK.Lambda/3.3.6.2
- AWSSDK.SecurityToken/3.3.1.9

Thanks for any help you can suggest!

Derek

Comment: If an AWS resource (e.g., EC2-Instance) calls your Lambda then it's only going to be able to tell you the role-id that was used to allow the resource to call your Lambda since there is no user-id available for a resource (e.g., EC2-Instance).